# splitting integral over a product space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $M=[0,a]\times\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure and let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive function.

Is it true that 
$$\int_M f(x,y)\; dx\; dy = \int_{[0,a]}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)\; dy\Big) \; dx= 
\int_\mathbb{R}\Big(\int_{[0,a]} f(x,y)\; dx\Big)\; dy\quad ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may do this as a consequence of Tonelli's Theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions